# Dependently and Dynamically change Combo Box Value List in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, combobox

In My C# WinForm, There are two `comboboxes` called `cmbTransFirstHelper` and `cmbTransSecondHelper`. Those comboboxes were populated from same table and same column in database. I used External `DataLoad` class for get data from database and those return DataTable type to the WinForm Class. There are two functions called `loadFirstHelper` and `loadSecondHelper` inside the winform's class to populate data to above comboboxes and those functions are calling when loading the form.

Now I want this, When I select a value in `cmbTransFirstHelper` combobox, that value should be removed from the `cmbTransSecondHelper` value list and also v/v.

Is it Possible ? and how can I Do that ?.

this is my DataLoad Class function that get data from database,

```
public DataTable loadEmployees(string category)
    {

        con.OpenConection();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = con.DataAdapter("select * from employees where employee_category ='"+ category +"'");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
        con.CloseConnection();

    }
```

these are my `loadFirstHelper` and `loadSecondHelper` functions

```
private void loadFirstHelper()
    {
        dt = dl.loadEmployees("Helper");
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select Helper--" };
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        cmbTransFirstHelper.ValueMember = "employee_id";
        cmbTransFirstHelper.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
        cmbTransFirstHelper.DataSource = dt;
    }
    private void loadSecondHelper()
    {
        dt = dl.loadEmployees("Helper");
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select Helper--" };
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        cmbTransSecondHelper.ValueMember = "employee_id";
        cmbTransSecondHelper.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
        cmbTransSecondHelper.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

this is how I call to above functions inside the formLoad Event

```
private void transVehicleINOUT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.loadVehicles();
        this.loadDiver();
        this.loadItems();
        this.loadFirstHelper();
        this.loadSecondHelper();
    }
```

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove item from by filtering existing DataSource of second comobobox.

```
var original = (DataTable)cmbTransSecondHelper.DataSource;
var selected = (int)cmbTransSecondHelper.SelectedValue;
var filtered = 
    original.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(row => row.Field<int>("employee_id") != selected)
            .CopyToDataTable();

cmbTransSecondHelper.DataSource = filtered;
```

If you want return removed value when another value was selected in the first combobox, you can save original collection in local variable and use it for filtering.

Use SqlParameters always when passing dynamic data to the sql query.
And if possible try to create and dispose new connection for every query.
Also load from database only the data you actually need, try not to use `SELECT * FROM`

In your particular case I wouldn't use "heavy" DataTable for only two fileds of data.
Create a class and use collection for using it as data source.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<Employee> LoadEmployees(string category)
{
    var query = 
"SELECT employee_id, employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_category=@category";
    var parameter = new SqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "@category",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Varchar,
        Value = category
    };
    var employees = new List<Employee>();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var employee = new Employee
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    Name = reader.GetString(1)
                };
                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }

        return employees;
    }
}
```

Then you can have only one function which fill given combobox with required data.

```
private void FillWithHelpers(ComboBox combobox)
{
    var select = new Employee { Id = 0, Name = "--Select Helper--" };
    var all = LoadEmployees("Helper");
    all.Insert(0, select);

    combobox.ValueMember = "Id";
    combobox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    combobox.DataSource = all;
}
```

Then in Load event handler call this function for both comoboboxes

```
private void TransVehicleINOUT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.loadVehicles();
    this.loadDiver();
    this.loadItems();
    this.FillWithHelpers(cmbTransFirstHelper);
    this.FillWithHelpers(cmbTransSecondHelper);
}
```

And in `SelectionChangeCommitted` eventhandler for first combobox you can easily filter selected value away.

```
private void cmbTransFirstHelper_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var original = (List<Employee>)cmbTransSecondHelper.DataSource;
    var selectedId = (int)cmbTransSecondHelper.SelectedValue;
    var filtered = 
        original.Where(employee => employee.Id != selectedId).ToList();

    cmbTransSecondHelper.DataSource = filtered;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this need to live inside of a selection changed event handler?

Comment: @trix, code can live anywhere, you can put it in dedicated function, which will be called anytime OP want remove already selected value. `SelectionChangeCommitted` can be good candidate for it.

Comment: @Fabio it is not working. if one selected, other one also automatically select that value. and if I try to do 2 or 3 times as v/v, it was return a error..